# Suppyling a hessian to fmin_ncg in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

For the SciPy function `fmin_ncg`, is there a way of suppling the hessian and gradient as a variable rather than a function?

I'm trying to rewrite some Matlab code in python. The code involves using an optimisation routine to fit some parameters to a set of data. To do this, I've supplied the gradient and hessian. E.g in Matlab I have something like this:

```
fmincon(@myFunc,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```

where `myFunc` returns 3 values: the function evaluation, the gradient, and the hessian.

However for `fmin_ncg` in Python it appears that the gradiant and hessian must be supplied as separate functions.

To me this seems inefficient as the code has to go through a large dataset, and there are calculations that are common to the function, the gradient and the hessian. e.g. Imagine a function `f(x) = a(x)*b(x)` with gradient `g(x) = a(x)*c(x)`, hessian `h(x) = a(x)*d(x)` ... in Matlab I can calculate `a(x)` once, where as it appears that i have to calculate this three times in python.

Have I misunderstood how `fmin_ncg` works or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a class that includes all of your functions.  Each iteration, the common variables are calculated during the first function call, then are reused for the other calls.  The callback feature of `fmin_ncg` can be used to reset the common variables at the end of each iteration.

```
class function(object):

   def __init__(self):
      self.commonVarsDirty = True

   def calcFunction(self,x,*args,**kwargs):
      if self.commonVarsDirty:
         self.calcCommonVars()
      return self.a*b

   def calcGradient(self,x,*args,**kwargs):
      if self.commonVarsDirty:
         self.calcCommonVars()
      return self.a*c

   def calcHessian(self,x,*args,**kwargs):
      if self.commonVarsDirty:
         self.calcCommonVars()
      return self.a*d

   def resetCommonVars(self,*args,**kwargs):
      self.commonVarsDirty = True

   def calcCommonVars(self):
      self.commonVarsDirty = False
      # calculate common variables and save them as class attributes
      self.a = 1+1
```

You would use it like this.

```
f = function()
fmin_ncg(f.calcFunction,x0,f.calcGradient,fhess=f.calcHessian,callback=f.resetCommonVars)
```

This adds some overhead so would only be worth it if the computation effort to calculate the common variables is significant.